# Detect Lock Screen in background application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, lockscreen, background-application

I have an application which runs in background mode. And when  the Lock Screen is active I need to perform some code. How do I detect when the lock screen is active from my background app?

Comment: What kind of background app is it? Only gps turn-by-turn apps actually _run_ in the background, all other types are periodically woken up by the OS.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There are ways to prevent the device from locking automatically, but you cannot detect and run code when the device is locked.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this unless you are writing code for a Jailbroken device.